# How Can I Match the Last String Using this REGEX

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I'm working on a bash script and need to use SED and a REGEX to match this line in a text file:

```
database.system = "pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword options='' application_name='myappname'";
```

This is the regex I've come up with:

```
database.system\s=\s((?=")(.*)(?=;))
```

So far my regex is matching everything except for the last semi-colon.  How do I modify the regex to catch the semi-colon as well?

Comment: The semi colon is not part of the string thou

Comment: now that i think of it, you're right.  so I should be able to get by with this regex yeah?

Comment: don't have a machine with me to confirm the pattern but by the look yes u should. Probably just append the ';' into the string and try it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using look-ahead assertions in your regular expression (`(?=...)`), which `sed` doesn't support.

However, you don't need them, if all you're trying to do is to extract the string inside the double quotes (using *GNU* `sed` syntax):

```
line=$'database.system = "pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword options=\'\' application_name=\'myappname\'";'

sed -rn 's/database\.system\s*=\s*"(.*)";/\1/p' <<<"$line"
# use var=$(sed ...) to capture command output in a variable.
```

will extract

```
pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5432 dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypassword options='' application_name='myappname'
```

- `-r` activates support for *extended* regular expressions, which function *more* like regular expressions in other languages (without `-r`, `sed` only supports *basic* regular expressions, whose feature set is limited and whose escaping rules are different).
- `-n` suppresses printing of each input line by default, so that an explicit output command is needed to produce output.
- `s/<regex>/<replacement>/p` matches each input line against `<regex>`, replaces it with `<replacement>`, and prints the result (`p`), but only if a match was found; `\1` refers to the first (and only, in this case) capture group (`(...)`) defined in .

The basic approach is to match the entire line, yet limit the (one and only) capture group to the substring of interest, and then replace the line with only the capture group, which effectively outputs only the substring of interest for each matching line.

Comment: Thank you!  that's exactly what I was looking to do.  Gonna spend sometime trying to understand exactly what you did, but this works. Thank you.

Comment: @KismetAgbasi My pleasure; see if my update makes it clearer what's going on.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, helps me understand and saves me time reading the manpage (that's what I was doing when I read your update).  My goal is to retrieve that string and pass it to a variable that I will later use in making a db query.  thanks again.